# numpy find slice along an axes where the first and last occurring value occurs

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array with integer values, something defined as:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0,  100, (10, 10, 10))
```

Now what I want to do is find the last slice (or alternatively the first slice) along a given axes (say  1) where a particular value occurs. At the moment, I do something like:

```
first=None
last=None
val = 20

for i in range(len(x.shape[1]):
    slice = x[:, i, :]
    if len(slice[slice==val]) > 0:
        if not first:
            first = i
        last = i

return first, last
```

This seems a bit unpythonic and I wonder if there is some `numpy` magic to do this?

Comment: please note that your loop will replace `first` if it actually is 0, since `if` statement see `0` and `None` both as `False`. The suggested answer takes care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can optimize this to be faster, but here is a vectorized version of what you search:

```
axis = 1
mask = np.where(x==val)[axis]
first, last = np.amin(mask), np.amax(mask)
```

It first finds the element `val` in your array using `np.where` and returns the `min` and `max` of indices along desired axis.

Answer (score 1):

Per your question, you want to check if there's any such valid slice and hence, get the start/first, stop/last indices. In absence of any such valid slice, we must return None's there. That needs extra check. Also, we can use `masking` to get those indices in an efficient manner, like so -

```
def slice_info(x, val):
    n = (x==val).any((0,2))
    if n.any():
        return n.argmax(), len(n)-n[::-1].argmax()-1
    else:
        return None,None
```

#### Benchmarking

Other proposed solution(s) :

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629916/ @Ehsan
def where_amin_amax(x, val):
    axis = 1
    mask = np.where(x==val)[axis]
    first, last = np.amin(mask), np.amax(mask)
    return first, last
```

Timings -

```
# Same setup as in given sample
In [157]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,  100, (10, 10, 10))

In [158]: %timeit where_amin_amax(x, val=20)
     ...: %timeit slice_info(x, val=20)
15.1 µs ± 287 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
9.63 µs ± 43.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Bigger
In [159]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,  100, (100, 100, 100))

In [160]: %timeit where_amin_amax(x, val=20)
     ...: %timeit slice_info(x, val=20)
3.34 ms ± 31.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
691 µs ± 3.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```